# Gmail label sorting: how to move a label to the bottom of the list

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, unicode

Gmail labels are sorted alphabetically, capitals don't make a difference. I can use tricks to change the sort order, like nesting, using characters like `!` or `_` or using emoticons. I want to move some labels to the absolute bottom of the list. It seems like Google decided to put A-Z after everything else.  What non-alphabet characters and symbols will sort after A-Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Unicode alphabet list: https://unicode-table.com/en/alphabets/

I took a guess, chose [Lydian](https://unicode-table.com/en/alphabets/lydian/), picked one character () and that moved the label down.

Comment: Yes it does, but visually it's not that nice. I suppose there are better characters or dingbats or emoticons than . Maybe I'll take the time to find something better later...

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Your implied question is "What characters and symbols will sort after the alphabet?" but the question would be improved if it is clearly stated to avoid ambiguity.  +10

Answer (score 2):

The Lydian letter A () can be used as the initial letter of an 'rchive' parent label that will appear after English-alphabet labels